# Datastax CE Cassandra migrate to Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have Datastax community edition 2.2.11 Cassandra with 90 nodes in a cluster. 
I am trying to migrate to Apache Cassandra 2.2.11

First I would like to try in my test environment but couldn't find any documentation Is there a pattern or a way that I should do the migration?

Anybody who has experience?

Answer (score 3):

Steps:

1. Alter the keyspaces using "EverywhereStrategy" to "SimpleStrategy". "EverywhereStrategy" is not supported by Apache cassandra.
   There's one or two keyspaces that uses it, dse_system is one of them.
2. Run nodetool drain before shutting down the existing Cassandra service.
3. Stop cassandra services.
4. Back up your Cassandra configuration files from the old installation.
5. Update java version if needed.
6. Install the binaries (via tarball, apt-get, yum, etc...) for the apache Cassandra.
7. Configure the new product.

   - Compare, merge and update any modifications you have previously made into the new configuration files for the apache version (cassandra.yaml, cassandra-env.sh, etc.).
8. Start the cassandra services.

   - Check the logs for warnings, errors, and exceptions.
     tail -f /var/logs/cassandra/system.log # or path where you set your logs.
9. Run nodetool upgradesstables

   - "nodetool upgradesstables"
     (The upgradesstables step can be run on each node after the nodes done with migration.)
10. Check the logs for warnings, errors, and exceptions.
    tail -f /var/logs/cassandra/system.log # or path where you set your logs.
11. Check the status of the cluster
    nodetool status
12. Repeat theses upgrade steps on each node in the cluster.